# What is the right way to query for capabilities in the OSGi container

Tags: osgi

I used to use the PackageAdmin.getBundles() to query for bundles installed by symbolicName and version range. But this class was deprecated.

Now I know that I should use capabilities and query bundles using the IdentityNamespace (in this case).

But what is the right and fastest way to query for capabilities being provided by ALL bundles installed in a container?

Should I create myself a method that gets an array of all bundles from BundleContext.getBundles(). Then traverse such array adapting each bundle for BundleRevision and then trying to match against the capabilities returned by its getDeclaredCapabilities() method ?  or there are other simple ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I create myself a method that gets an array of all bundles from BundleContext.getBundles(). Then traverse such array adapting each bundle for BundleRevision and then trying to match against the capabilities returned by its getDeclaredCapabilities() method ? or there are other simple ways?

Almost. You should:

- Get the available bundles from bundleContext
- adapt the bundles to BundleWirings
- get the capabilities from BundleWirings

e.g.:

```
Bundle[] bundles = context.getBundles();
foreach(Bundle : bundles) {
    BundleWiring bundleWiring = bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class);
    List<BundleCapability> capabilities = bundleWiring.getCapabilities(null);
    myCapabilityBasedLogic(capabilities);
}
```

For more information, see the [documentation of BundleWiring](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/wiring/BundleWiring.html) class.

**Update**

In case a Bundle is in installed state, it has no BundleWiring. I wrote a code snippet to get the capabilities of the installed bundles before: https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-lqmg/blob/master/src/main/java/org/everit/osgi/dev/lqmg/internal/EquinoxHackUtilImpl.java.

See the function *getAllCapabilities(bundles, state)*.

The relevant code snippet:

```
PlatformAdmin platformAdmin = systemBundleContext.getService(platformServiceSR);
State state = platformAdmin.getState();
Bundle[] bundles = systemBundleContext.getBundles();

List<BundleCapability> availableCapabilities = new ArrayList<BundleCapability>();
for (Bundle bundle : bundles) {
    BundleDescription bundleDescription = state.getBundle(bundle.getBundleId());
    List<BundleCapability> declaredCapabilities = bundleDescription.getDeclaredCapabilities(null);
    availableCapabilities.addAll(declaredCapabilities);
}
return availableCapabilities;
```

I guess there is a similar possibility in Felix. If you find out how it works, please share it with me and I will create a HackUtil implementation for Felix, too ;).

If you want an universal handmade solution, you can parse the *Provide-Capability* and *Export-Package* headers of the installed Bundle. You can parse a header with felix-utils. This library is embedded into many technologies, butI also re-packaged it and uploaded it to maven-central as an [OSGi bundle](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.everit.osgi.bundles%7Corg.everit.osgi.bundles.org.apache.felix.utils%7C1.6.0%7Cjar). You code can look similar to the following:

```
Dictionary<String, String> headers = installedBundle.getHeaders();
String header = headers.get("Provide-Capability");

if (header != null) {
    // Parse with felix-utils
    Clause[] clauses = Parse.parseHeader(header);
    for(Clause clause : clauses) {
        String nameSpace = clause.getName();
        Attribute[] attributes = clause.getAttributes();
        Directive[] directives = clause.getDirectives();

        processCapability(nameSpace, attributes, directives);
    }
}
```

You must implement *processCapability* as you want. You can also parse the *Export-Package* headers and convert them to capabilities based on the OSGi spec.

Comment: Well, my understood was that a bundle doesn't have a BundleWiring when its state is Installed. isn't that right ?

Comment: You are right. I thought you needed the available capabilities only. Updated the answer with all the information I know at the moment :).